# Get IP address from snort packet - UNSOCK

Tags: c, sockets, snort

I am using a socket to receive alert information from snort packets.
I am using the readme-unsock file as a base. I cant extract the IP addresses from the packet. I get the wrong data structure from the packet. is there a way of changing this? (Apologies i'm new)

```
case IPPROTO_TCP:
        inet_ntoa (p->iph->ip_dst);
```

[Error message received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smZAp.png)

Comment: You really need to learn the language before you venture into raw sockets parsing.

Answer (score 0):

**inet_ntoa()** is deprected -   https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html

use **inet_ntop()** instead - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html